# How to apply indentation to all lines when injecting multi-line strings in formatted text blocks

Tags: java, string-interpolation, java-text-blocks

I started using Java 15 text blocks which are nice for readability. Now I want to format text blocks and inject strings in them, and from what I understand the idiomatic way to do this right now is to use [String::formatted](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#formatted(java.lang.Object...)). But it seems that source-code indentation in text blocks is a bit limited when injecting multi-line strings.

For example, the following program:

```
class Scratch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String text = """
            Hello!
            This is a text block!
            """;

        System.out.println(text);

    }

}
```

prints the two lines without any indentation, as expected:

```
Hello!
This is a text block!
```

However, this one:

```
class Scratch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String text = """
            Hello!
            This is a text block!
            """;

        String wrapperText = """
            Hello again, now I'd like the entire text below to be indented with a single tab:
                %s
            """.formatted(text);

        System.out.println(wrapperText);

    }

}
```

prints the following:

```
Hello again, now I'd like the entire text below to be indented with a single tab:
    Hello!
This is a text block!
```

whereas I was kind of hoping to get the following:

```
Hello again, now I'd like the entire text below to be indented with a single tab:
    Hello!
    This is a text block!
```

I do realize that the problem has nothing to do with the fact that `text` is a text block in my second program, it might as well have been a traditional string literal with a new line character `\n`, and the outcome would have been the same. The wrapper text block clearly only applies the indentation to the first line of the injected multi-line string, which is understandable as it is probably just appending the injected string as it is after the indentation.

So I guess my question is: is there a clean way to apply **the indentation specified in the wrapper text block** to all lines of the injected string?

I know I could do something like `.formatted(text.replaceAll("\n", "\n\t"))` to format the text block, but that is clumsy, makes assumptions about the line termination sequence, and defeats the purpose of having the indentation specified in one place, cause then if I want to update the indentation, I would need to do it both in the text block and in the replacement string.

Comment: The _cleanest way_ of doing that would be to wrap this behaviour in a function. This way, you could centralize where your indentation is defined, and still use the _clumsy way_ you've described.

Comment: @Nicolas I'm not sure what that would look like concretely. I would appreciate it if you could write an answer with a short example :)

Comment: Since text blocks always use `\n` as line terminator, there is no problem if your workaround makes assumptions about the line terminator (as long as the assumption is that the line terminator is `\n`).

Answer (score 0):

I use Java 8.  Here's one method to indent a multi-line `String`.

Here are the test results from one of my tests.

```
Hello!
This is a text block!

Hello again, now I'd like the entire text below to be indented with 4 spaces:
    Hello!
    This is a text block!
```

You may have to adjust the `indent` method to work with Java 15.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
public class TextIndentationTesting {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TextIndentationTesting tit = new TextIndentationTesting();

        String text = "Hello!\nThis is a text block!";
        System.out.println(text);
        System.out.println();

        String wrapperText = "Hello again, now I'd like the entire text below "
                + "to be indented with 4 spaces:";
        System.out.println(wrapperText + "\n" + tit.indent(text, 4));
    }

    public String indent(String text, int indentation) {
        // Create the indent space
        StringBuilder indentBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int index = 0; index < indentation; index++) {
            indentBuilder.append(' ');
        }
        String indentSpace = indentBuilder.toString();

        // Indent the text
        String lineSeparator = Character.toString((char) 10);
        String replacement = lineSeparator + indentSpace;
        text = text.replaceAll(lineSeparator, replacement);

        return indentSpace + text;
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, to me this would not work for a couple of reasons: 1) it does not use Java 15 text blocks, or any other feature of the language to write text with the same advantages of text blocks such as improved source-code readability; 2) it does `System.out.println(wrapperText + "\n" + tit.indent(text, 4));` so it's kind of specific to my example where I inject only one string at the very end of the wrapper text, what if I have a long text block with multiple format specifiers? It becomes unwieldy very quickly; 3) it does not really improve on the workaround I mentioned at the end of my question...